# Why Render looks smudgy in cycle engine

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, node-editor, denoise

I'm having a rendering problem here in blender. The render looks smudgy and this never happened before. Usually, I use a very standard amount of samples around 128-256. I use the blender 3.0 version and cycles engine.

I've already tried everything such as increasing the number of samples, enabling and disabling the denoise settings, using the denoise node, and even I try to increase the number of bounces.
Do you guys have any idea to fix this? it's just annoying

[image: composition denoise nodes]
[image: render settings]
[image: the end result close up]

Comment: Isn't this just denoising artifacts?

Comment: What resolution are you rendering at? The settings we can see look okay to me. Unless you're using both of those denoisers together?

Comment: What happenes when volumetric is off? ... probably better to share simplyfied blend just with an element still producing the issue https://blend-exchange.com/